Tensorflow crashing with libffi.so.6 error
I am trying to run tensor flow in Python 3.7.4 and TensorFlow 2.16.1. As soon as I try to import Tensorflow, it crashes with the following error -
ImportError: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked the version of libffi and it shows as follows -
/usr/lib/libffi.so.8.1.0
/usr/lib/libffi.so.8

I also tried to create a symlink, but I do not have the permissions to do it. Is there a way to solve this issue?

What Linux distro and version are you on? How did you install Python and TensorFlow?

HI @Shreya,The ImportError: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error indicates that TensorFlow is trying to use libffi.so.6, but your system has libffi.so.8 installed. This typically happens when there is a mismatch between the expected library versions by TensorFlow and what is available on your system.Since TensorFlow is looking for libffi.so.6, you need to install the correct version of libffi. On many Linux distributions, you can install libffi6 using the package manager.
